# PHP : How to delete elements from one associative array using another associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, array-difference

I have two arrays one which has all the data, and another associative array of the keys I would like to remove.

```
$all_data = array(
    'one' =>array(
        'one_one'=>array(
            'one_one_one'=>'value',
            'one_one_two'=>'value',
        ),
        'one_two'=> array(
            'one_two_one'=>'value',
            'one_two_two'=>'value',
        )
    ),
    'two' =>array(
        'two_one'=>array(
            'two_one_one' =>'value',
            'two_one_two' =>'value',
        ),
        'two_two'=>array(
            'two_two_one'=>'value',
            'two_two_two'=>'value',
        )
    )
);
$remove_elements = array(
    'one' =>array(
        'one_one',
        'one_two'=> array(
            'one_two_one',
        )
    ),
    'two'
);
```

The output I would like would look like this.

```
$result = array(
    'one' =>array(
        'one_two'=> array(
            'one_two_two'=>'value',
        )
    )
);
```

I have tried array_diff but I get a "Array to string conversion" error, I assume this is because they are nested arrays.

i created a function but ii cant get it to work.

```
function arrayRecursiveUnset($array_1, $array_2) {

  foreach ($array_1 as $array_1_key => $array_1_value) {

    if (array_key_exists($array_1_key, $array_2)) {

      if (is_array($array_1_value)) {

        $array_1[$array_1_key] = arrayRecursiveUnset($array_1_value, $array_2[$array_1_key]);

      } else {
        unset($array_1[$array_1_key]);
      }
    } 
  }
  return $array_1;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Sounds more like _do this for me_

Comment: @TreeTree, ive added what ive tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It hasn't been thoroughly tested but it seems to be working for what I need it for. hope this helps someone.

```
function arrayRecursiveUnset($array_1, $array_2) {

    foreach ($array_1 as $array_1_key => $array_1_value) {

        if (array_key_exists($array_1_key, $array_2)) {

            if (is_array($array_1_value)) {

                $array_1[$array_1_key] = arrayRecursiveUnset($array_1_value, $array_2[$array_1_key]);

            } else {

                unset($array_1[$array_1_key]);
            }
        } else if (in_array($array_1_key, $array_2)){
            unset($array_1[$array_1_key]);
        } 
    }
    return $array_1;
} 


$result = arrayRecursiveUnset(  $all_data  , $remove_elements);
```